# Summation: $\sum_{k=0}^{k=m}\frac{1}{k+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, harmonic-numbers

While working on a larger problem I reach a step where I need to know
$\sum_{k=0}^{k=m}\frac{1}{k+1}$, as well as  $\sum_0^n \frac{1}{k+2}$.

Is there a known formula/rule for these? (I am hoping there may be something similar to the known summations of infinite series).

Comment: You might want to look at [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).  These are unbounded, and there is no closed form though there are good approximations

Answer (score 1):

You basically have: $$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k}=H(n+1)$$Where $H(n)$ is known as the $n$th harmonic number. The other sum you have is $H(n+2)-1$. Now the thing about the harmonic numbers is that there is no closed form formula for them. However, we do know that $$H(n)=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}dx$$

Comment: Strictly speaking $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k+1}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k}=H(n+1)$ and $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k+2}=H(n+2)-1$

Comment: @Henry Thanks for noting this.

Comment: Abel's formula  helps.

Answer (score 0):

Harmonic numbers can be written in terms of the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)
$$
\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{1}{k+1} = \psi(m+2)+\gamma
$$
But I doubt that is of use in the OP.